# Start conversation without user interaction in Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Is it possible to send a message to a user without the user interacting with the bot first?
I'm using the following guide to retrieve *psids* from users that have already connected their profile to an app that I own.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/connecting-accounts.
For users that have at least one interaction with a page that I also own, I'm able to get their id. For all other users the endpoint returns an empty array.
Im aware of customer matching but is that the only way to achieve this?

Comment: Of course that is not possible any other way besides account matching. Users do not want to get spammed by every dummy out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a message by bot before the user initializes the conversation.

Facebook Messanger Bot permits a standard messages, with a 24-hour interval 
to reply to a message initiated by a user. In Some specific cases, Facebook permits to send a message after this time.

A message are triggerd when the user either sends a message to a company or clicks a call button for action in Messenger, or when the user requests a message from a company through a plugin, such as send to Messenger.

Check out the policies here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy-overview

Comment: You are correct for all cases of bots without `subscription_messaging` permissions.

Answer (score 0):

**You are correct, customer matching is your only option for this.**

Just learned this today, if you have a user's phone number, you can message them unprompted. You also need the `pages_messaging_phone_number` permission, which you can only get by paying the $99 customer matching fee.

Check the docs on sending to phone numbers [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/customer-matching). Customer matching docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/customer-matching)